# How to enforce Jenkins security to prevent a user from being able to execute commands under another user's account

Tags: security, jenkins

For example, user1 created a job1 which can be executed on node1 where a jenkins slave agent is connected to host1 with user1's credential.

There is a security risk:

- User2 can edit this job1, and run any commands in user1's name at host1.
- Or a user3 can create a new job2 to connect to node1 and run any commands at host1 with user1's account

How can we avoid this?

I'm already using role-strategy and having users in different roles such as JobCreator/Editor/NodeCreator etc. But it doesn't resolve the issue: we certainly have more than 1 user having e.g. JobCreator or editor roles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that „*using role-strategy*“ refers to the [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) which allows:

> Creating **project roles**, allowing to set only Job and Run permissions on a project basis.

Allows to prevent your *user2* to be able to edit your *job1* by applying proper *project* patterns.

> Creating **slave roles**, allowing to set node-related permissions.

Allows to prevent your *user3* to execute jobs on *node1* by applying proper *node* patterns.

Note: Unfortunately the user guide on the plugin's page is outdated: It does not mention slave roles. Furthermore, the inline help of *Slave roles* → *Pattern* is wrong, as well. It's just a C&P of the project role's pattern inline help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes I use Role strategy plugin. I'm also using the project roles, but currently more than 2 persons have job edit permission on a given project (the procedure shouldn't be blocked due to a vacation for example).

Comment: About the slave role, my understanding is that each user needs to create its own node associated with its account and we can then setup a pattern so that each user can only execute a job on its own node (under its own account). I'll try this.

Comment: If we can limit to have only 1 admin for each project and a node who can only be used by 1 person. The project and slave roles resolve the issue. However, in the real world situation where the nodes and jobs can be used by a few members, the risk still exists.